# RxJS: Creating and Subscribing observable onClick

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have this template:

```
<button (click)="action()">Action</button>
```

And the following JS:

```
function action() {
  const obs$ = of(true).pipe(delay(500));

  obs$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(...);
}
```

I was wondering if it was acceptable to basically create a new Observable everytime I click on a button. It has a `take(1)` thus I don't think memory leak is an issue here, but I wonder if it wasn't better to declare my observable earlier on and just attach/detach the subscription on it.

Comment: This will still emit however. It's probably better to unsubscribe.

Comment: Despite the take(1) ?

Comment: Even with `take(1)` the source Observable still has to emit until it's unsubscribed and disposed.

Comment: You could use the `fromEvent` method to create your Observable from the click, and use a mapping operator like `switchMap` to subscribe to another Observable if need be. Also, as long as your Observable emits, `take(1)` means you won't have memory leak issues, as it will emit once and then complete. No leftover subscription issues.

Comment: @WillAlexander i totally agree with you, can you post your comment as an answer, so that we can reduce the un-answered stack of rxjs questions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you give your button a local reference:

```html
<button #myButton>Click me!</button>
```

And then in TS:

```js
@ViewChild() myButton: ElementRef;
clicks$: Observable<any>;
destroy$: Observable<boolean>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.clicks$ = fromEvent(this.myButton.nativeElement, 'click').pipe(
    takeUntil(this.destroy$),
    //...
  ).subscribe();
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.destroy$.next(true);
}
```

Only subscribe in TS if absolutely necessary.